# Firebase Emulator TIMEOUT: Port 8080 on localhost was not active within 60000ms

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-tools

I've tried to set up Firebase Local Emulator Suite on Next.js app by following the [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_and_prototype?database=RTDB) on Firebase docs.
But when I run:

```
$ firebase emulators:start
```

My terminal returned an error:

```
⚠  emulators: Support for Java version <= 10 will be dropped soon in firebase-tools@11. Please upgrade to Java version 11 or above to continue using the emulators.
i  emulators: Starting emulators: auth, functions, firestore, database, hosting, pubsub, storage
⚠  Your requested "node" version "16" doesn't match your global version "17". Using node@17 from host.
i  firestore: Firestore Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log
i  emulators: Shutting down emulators.
i  functions: Stopping Functions Emulator
i  firestore: Stopping Firestore Emulator
i  hub: Stopping emulator hub

Error: TIMEOUT: Port 8080 on localhost was not active within 60000ms
```

Here's my [localhost:8080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFPLK.png)

Comment: I have the same issue with the Python `firebase-admin`. I've set an env var to `FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8080` and it's also timing out. My localhost looks the same as in the screenshot.